# Why can't I run my Django project using PostgreSQL?

Tags: python, django, postgresql

Firstly, I'm on Windows 10.

I just started learning Django. I did the tutorials that are with the Django documentation. I need to program an app that uses a PostgreSQL database. This is for a test following up a job interview, so I don't want to mess this up.

When I run the command "python manage.py runserver", I run into the following error :

```
d:\Utilisateur\Documents\code\code_python\Django\Psycle_test\mysite>python manage.py runserver
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Utilisateur\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 217, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Users\Utilisateur\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 195, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "C:\Users\Utilisateur\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\postgresql\base.py", line 178, in get_new_connection
    connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "C:\Users\Utilisateur\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\psycopg2\__init__.py", line 126, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
psycopg2.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061)
        Is the server running on host "127.0.0.1" and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

The Django documentation says that I need to install psycopg2. Which I did using the command "pip install psycopg2". I configured settings.py in my Django project in order to use a PostgreSQL database :

```py
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'myDataBase',
        'USER': 'myDataBaseUser',
        'PASSWORD': 'password',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
```

Changing 'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql' to 'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2' gives me the same error.

I also tried to change '127.0.0.1' to 'localhost' and it still doesn't work.

(The different topics I've seen talk about a postgresql.conf file, but I can't seem to find it anywhere, if it can even solve anything anyway.)

What am I doing wrong?

### Edit

After installing PostgreSQL 9.6, creating myDataBase, creating a role myDataBaseUser and granting the privileges to that role, I now get that error:

```
d:\Utilisateur\Documents\code\code_python\Django\Psycle_test\mysite>python manage.py runserver
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Utilisateur\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 217, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Users\Utilisateur\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 195, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "C:\Users\Utilisateur\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\postgresql\base.py", line 178, in get_new_connection
    connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "C:\Users\Utilisateur\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\psycopg2\__init__.py", line 126, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
psycopg2.OperationalError

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Utilisateur\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\Utilisateur\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\threading.py", line 864, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Utilisateur\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 54, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Utilisateur\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 120, in inner_run
    self.check_migrations()
  File "C:\Users\Utilisateur\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 453, in check_migrations
    executor = MigrationExecutor(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS])
  File "C:\Users\Utilisateur\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 18, in __init__
    self.loader = MigrationLoader(self.connection)
  File "C:\Users\Utilisateur\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\loader.py", line 49, in __init__
    self.build_graph()
  File "C:\Users\Utilisateur\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\loader.py", line 212, in build_graph
    self.applied_migrations = recorder.applied_migrations()
  File "C:\Users\Utilisateur\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\recorder.py", line 73, in applied_migrations
    if self.has_table():
  File "C:\Users\Utilisateur\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\recorder.py", line 56, in has_table
    return self.Migration._meta.db_table in self.connection.introspection.table_names(self.connection.cursor())
  File "C:\Users\Utilisateur\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 256, in cursor
    return self._cursor()
  File "C:\Users\Utilisateur\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 233, in _cursor
    self.ensure_connection()
  File "C:\Users\Utilisateur\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 217, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Users\Utilisateur\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 89, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "C:\Users\Utilisateur\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 217, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Users\Utilisateur\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 195, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "C:\Users\Utilisateur\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\postgresql\base.py", line 178, in get_new_connection
    connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "C:\Users\Utilisateur\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\psycopg2\__init__.py", line 126, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
django.db.utils.OperationalError
```

Comment: You seems to not have postgresql installed or launched or your firewall blocking access to it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you dont have postgres database installed locally. Download it from [here](https://www.postgresql.org/download/windows/)

Then going into console you need to create database by `create database myDataBase;`

create role by `create role myDataBaseUser with password 'password'`. Grant privileges to the role by

`grant all privileges on database "myDataBase" to myDataBaseUser`.

Then you will 
be able to connect.

Comment: Thanks! However, now I get the error :
```
conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
psycopg2.OperationalError
```

Comment: try changing port '5432' to 5432 @Axil

Comment: It finally works! Apparently "mydatabaseuser" was not allowed to connect to "mydatabase". I changed that and now it works!
Thanks!!!